# Using paramiko to tunnel an MySql port when django starts

Tags: django, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to connect to a remote MySql server from my local machine.
I want to run it whenever the DEBUG constant is set to true.

Here's the script:

```
import select
import SocketServer
import sys
import threading
import paramiko

SSH_PORT = 22
DEFAULT_PORT = 4000

g_verbose = True


class ForwardServer (SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer):
    daemon_threads = True
    allow_reuse_address = True


class Handler (SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        try:
            chan = self.ssh_transport.open_channel('direct-tcpip',
                                                   (self.chain_host, self.chain_port),
                                                   self.request.getpeername())
        except Exception, e:
            verbose('Incoming request to %s:%d failed: %s' % (self.chain_host,
                                                              self.chain_port,
                                                              repr(e)))
            return
        if chan is None:
            verbose('Incoming request to %s:%d was rejected by the SSH server.' %
                    (self.chain_host, self.chain_port))
            return

        verbose('Connected!  Tunnel open %r -> %r -> %r' % (self.request.getpeername(),
                                                            chan.getpeername(), (self.chain_host, self.chain_port)))
        while True:
            r, w, x = select.select([self.request, chan], [], [])
            if self.request in r:
                data = self.request.recv(1024)
                if len(data) == 0:
                    break
                chan.send(data)
            if chan in r:
                data = chan.recv(1024)
                if len(data) == 0:
                    break
                self.request.send(data)
        chan.close()
        self.request.close()
        verbose('Tunnel closed from %r' % (self.request.getpeername(),))


def forward_tunnel(local_port, remote_host, remote_port, transport):
    # this is a little convoluted, but lets me configure things for the Handler
    # object.  (SocketServer doesn't give Handlers any way to access the outer
    # server normally.)
    class SubHander (Handler):
        chain_host = remote_host
        chain_port = remote_port
        ssh_transport = transport
    ForwardServer(('', local_port), SubHander).serve_forever()


def verbose(s):
    if g_verbose:
        print s


HELP = """\
Set up a forward tunnel across an SSH server, using paramiko. A local port
(given with -p) is forwarded across an SSH session to an address:port from
the SSH server. This is similar to the openssh -L option.
"""

def forward():
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())

    try:
        print 'connecting'

        client.connect('*******', username='***', password='****!')

        print 'connected'
    except Exception, e:
        print '*** Failed to connect to %s:%d: %r' % ('*****', 22, e)
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        forward_tunnel(3306, '127.0.0.1', 3306, client.get_transport())
    except SystemExit:
        print 'C-c: Port forwarding stopped.'
        sys.exit(0)
```

I have two problems here:
1) I don't know how and when to call my forward function when django raises.
2) When I access django locally and run the script from the console I get the following exception:

> exception happened during
>   processing of request from
>   ('127.0.0.1', 41872) Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py",
>   line 558, in process_request_thread
>       self.finish_request(request, client_address)   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py",
>   line 320, in finish_request
>       self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py",
>   line 615, in **init**
>       self.handle()   File "/home/omer/Aptana Studio 3
>   Workspace/Website/src/ssh_tunnel/tunnel.py",
>   line 51, in handle
>       verbose('Tunnel closed from %r' % (self.request.getpeername(),))   File
>   "", line 1, in getpeername
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py",
>   line 165, in _dummy
>       raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor') error: [Errno 9] Bad file
>   descriptor

Was this a bad idea to begin with?
Should I do this manually every time?

Comment: create the ssh session when you fire up the server instead. Use a shell script.  Look at using ssh host key authentication.  This allows you to have the script connect the ssh session without asking for a username and password.

Comment: @kevpie: Why what I did is a bad idea?

Comment: It is 100 lines of code to do what @damir has written.  What is connecting over the tunnel to mysql, an admin client, developer web server?

Comment: When and where does the Debug constant get set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a bad idea.

I don't think you need to do it manually.

The exception is a bug in paramiko's forward code sample. This has been addressed by jhalcrow in the pull request here:

https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/36

This post has some code to do it in a more event driven way, i.e if you wanted to call it via some web event hooks in your django code or the like:

[Paramiko SSH Tunnel Shutdown Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414082/paramiko-ssh-tunnel-shutdown-issue)

Answer (score 1):

humm, i didn't try this, but if you are on linux, could you run

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 remote.host.ip
```

through python system call when DEBUG is set?

also if you are on Windows, try putty with port forwarding

Comment: Yes but this has some problems: First, you can't close the connection so whenever the server terminates that connection is opened forever. Second, when you try to open the connection again you get an error because the tunnel is already opened and your django server won't run.

Comment: Here's the python command to do what you suggested: `subprocess.call(shlex.split("ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 omerkatz@web165.webfaction.com"))`

Comment: Is this production stuff or would you be satisfied with a hack? you could run this command once with def() and put decorator in front of the function to check for existance of some /tmp/.lock before running ssh tunnel again. What we do in my company is start vpn tunnel to remote host (openvpn) and based on environment variables we use different settings. I can copypaste stuff here if you want

Comment: This isn't for production. It's for local development with the remote SQL dev server.